# Receive javascript response in TCP socket (c++)

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers

I'm making a program that simulates a camera hardware, so I can pass any image and it will display as a camera image.

To acomplish this I need to get the buffer (arr) from image on my js code:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function encodePngAsRGBA(element) {
  var file = element.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = () => {
      const w = img.naturalWidth, h = img.naturalHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
      const arr = Uint8ClampedArray.from(imgData.data);
      console.log(`image width: ${w}, image height: ${h}, expected raw data size (w x h x 4): ${w * h * 4}, actual size: ${arr.length}`);
      console.log(arr);
    };
    img.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" onchange="encodePngAsRGBA(this)" />

    <script src="image_to_buffer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Send to my TCP server:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

class Server_socket{
    fstream file;

    int PORT;
    
    int general_socket_descriptor;
    int new_socket_descriptor;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int address_length;

    public:
        Server_socket(){
            create_socket();
            PORT = 8050;

            address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
            address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
            address_length = sizeof(address);

            bind_socket();
            set_listen_set();
            accept_connection();

            file.open(".//Data//Server//server_text.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
            if(file.is_open()){
                cout<<"[LOG] : File is ready to Transmit.\n";
            }
            else{
                cout<<"[ERROR] : File loading failed, Exititng.\n";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        void create_socket(){
            if ((general_socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : Socket failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Socket Created Successfully.\n";
        }

        void bind_socket(){
            if (bind(general_socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
                perror("[ERROR] : Bind failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Bind Successful.\n";
        }

        void set_listen_set(){
            if (listen(general_socket_descriptor, 3) < 0) {
                perror("[ERROR] : Listen");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Socket in Listen State (Max Connection Queue: 3)\n";
        }

        void accept_connection(){
            if ((new_socket_descriptor = accept(general_socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&address_length))<0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : Accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Connected to Client.\n";
        }

        void transmit_file(){
            std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
            cout<<"[LOG] : Transmission Data Size "<<contents.length()<<" Bytes.\n";

            cout<<"[LOG] : Sending...\n";

            int bytes_sent = send(new_socket_descriptor , contents.c_str() , contents.length() , 0 );
            cout<<"[LOG] : Transmitted Data Size "<<bytes_sent<<" Bytes.\n";

            cout<<"[LOG] : File Transfer Complete.\n";
        }
};

int main(){
    Server_socket S;
    S.transmit_file();
    return 0;
}
```

**And Then send to my TCP client:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

class Client_socket{
    fstream file;

    int PORT;
    
    int general_socket_descriptor;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int address_length;

    public:
        Client_socket(){
            create_socket();
            PORT = 8050;

            address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
            address_length = sizeof(address);
            if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr)<=0) { 
                cout<<"[ERROR] : Invalid address\n";
            }

            create_connection();
            
            file.open(".//Data//Client//client_text.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
            if(file.is_open()){
                cout<<"[LOG] : File Creted.\n";
            }
            else{
                cout<<"[ERROR] : File creation failed, Exititng.\n";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        void create_socket(){
            if ((general_socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : Socket failed.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Socket Created Successfully.\n";
        }

        void create_connection(){
            if (connect(general_socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : connection attempt failed.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Connection Successfull.\n";
        }

        void receive_file(){
            char buffer[1024] = {};
            int valread = read(general_socket_descriptor , buffer, 1024);
            cout<<"[LOG] : Data received "<<valread<<" bytes\n";
            cout<<"[LOG] : Saving data to file.\n";
            
            file<<buffer;
            cout<<"[LOG] : File Saved.\n";
        }
};

int main(){
    Client_socket C;
    C.receive_file();
    return 0;
}
```

**The question is:**

How can i receive the buffer from my JS code, open in my TCP server and send to my TCP client, and instead of save the file, I'd like to cache the buffer inside a variable and the send to another function

Comment: Your options are HTTP requests or websockets. Web browser Javascript code is deliberately very limited.

Comment: in fact, i dont even need the js part, I updated the code to get a file in the folder and send via tcp, i just need to know how to convert this file (png) into RGBA_8888

Comment: you could use libpng?